# Checking if a float is an even number before printing it

Tags: c++

I have a `float` that has a value like this: `0.012447`, I want to rescale the value I have between `0.0 - 1.0` and use it to display a percentage, but I would like to only display **even** values, like `... 12%, 14%, 16%, ...`

Something like this:

```
float percent = ....
int value = percent * 100;

if(value == 12 || value == 14 || value == 16 .....){
 printf("Result: = %f\n", percent);
}
```

If there is an easy way to do it without using the `percent * 10` and multiple `ifs` i would like examples

Comment: I would suggest you round `value` and then mod (%) it by 2. If the result is 1, then you have an odd number and if the result is 2 then you have an even number; ie multiples of 2.

Comment: have an example?

Comment: @RisingSun if OP wants just to round down to 2, it is much simpler to do - `value &= ~1;` to round to nearest `value += value & 1;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know the difference, it was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a complement to @salcc's answer, this is probably close to what you ask for; conditional printing of `value` if it's even.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(float percent = 0.f; percent <= 1.f; percent += 1.f / 47.f) {
        int value = static_cast<int>(std::round(percent * 100.f));
        if(value % 2 == 0) { // Is it even? If so, print it.
            std::cout << "Result: = " << value << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

What's really bad with this approach is that it may create gaps in the output. The above creates this output:

```
Result: = 0
Result: = 2
Result: = 4
Result: = 6
Result: = 26
Result: = 28
Result: = 30
Result: = 32
Result: = 34
Result: = 36
Result: = 38
Result: = 40
Result: = 60
Result: = 62
Result: = 64
Result: = 66
Result: = 68
Result: = 70
Result: = 72
Result: = 74
Result: = 94
Result: = 96
Result: = 98
Result: = 100
```

Comment: This was meant as an example of what happens if you don't think things through. It solves the original problem, but it is a bad solution. Look at @salcc's instead.

Answer (score 3):

To round to the nearest even number you can divide the number by two, round the result, and then multiply it by two. You can do that and convert it to a percentage by just doing:

```
printf("Result: %g%%\n", round(percent * 100 / 2.0) * 2);
```

To use the `round()` function, you have to put `#include <cmath>` at the top of the file.

---

Demo:

```
float percent = 0.129;
printf("Result: %g%%\n", round(percent * 100 / 2.0) * 2);
```

Output:

```
Result: 12%
```

Comment: How do I check this through if, I would like to print only if the value is at 12, 14, 16 etc?

Comment: This will always output a value which is even (divisible by two without a remainder), so you don't need to check it.

Comment: @Stan The good thing about this approach is that you won't get progress gaps if you happen to get a series of values that are odd. I'll provide an answer to demostrate that.